# Difference between Linux text mode and Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, linux

I don't know if this is a dumb question or not but again as my professor says if you have doubts then clear them . What is the difference between Linux text mode and windows command prompt (cmd). I know both windows and Linux are different Operating Systems but when you look at the commands, some of the commands are common For Example `cd command`.

Comment: SO seems like the wrong place for this question. Also question is somewhat to generic. In short: windows cmd sux and is barely usefull and in linux it depends on which shell one uses(which kan be very powerfull)

Comment: Aside from SO not being the best place for this kind of question, I have to disagree, Windows Command Prompt is not "barely useful", it's just not as necessary on a system that mainly uses graphical context, but it certainly can be and is useful when it's needed, and Windows sysadmins have at their hands Windows Powershell, that is a replacement to Command Prompt and it's very powerful, even more to those who are experienced with .NET, but that's not a prerequisite. It's valid to bring this to the table, since *nix systems also have more than one shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both based on the same idea and are called Command-Line Interfaces (see wikipedia). They operate off the same principals, just using different keywords to perform similar commands. It should be noted however, that the commands although similarly named, may not perform the exact same function. They are just abstractions of lower level functions of the operating system. Just like people can explain similar ideas using different words and phrases, the same applies in this situation. For reference here's a list of Bash commands: http://ss64.com/bash/ and the same website has windows commands.

Comment: Two salient points: (a) unix (of which linux is merely one kind) has a lot more commands than Windows, and a range of commands which can do a lot more, because the shell is the primary interface, rather than the window system and (b) the shell itself, the program which interprets your input and runs commands, is rather more sophisticated on unix than on Windows, and can do all sorts of redirection, conditionals, looping and so on and so forth. The Windows shell is a a fairly rudimentary thing (certainly still useful!) whereas the unix shell is a powerful working and programming environment.

Answer (score 6):

Although superficially similar in some ways, the two command line interfaces have different lineages:

- The Windows command prompt is based heavily on that of MS-DOS / PC-DOS, which in turn was based on the CP/M Console Command Processor.  The CP/M CCP interface was itself based on an earlier operating system called RSTS.
- The Linux shells trace their roots back to the original UNIX Thompson shell; the Thompson shell borrowed from the Multics shell (where the term "*shell*" originated).

Traces of these are still evident today - the `DIR` command in the Windows command prompt can be traced all the way back to the `DIR` command in RSTS, and similarly the `ls` command in GNU coreutils can be traced back to the Multics "list segments" command.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the operating system. The command prompt (cmd) and a terminal emulator (linux bash shell or similar) are text interfaces to the operating system. They allow you to manipulate the file system and run programs without the graphical interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about Linux shells. The **Bash** shell for instance, is among the most used Linux shells... ever!

http://doc.dev.md/lsst/ch01sec07.html

http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/shell.html

And if you're looking for a list of commands: http://www.physics.ubc.ca/mbelab/computer/linux-intro/html/

Answer (score 0):

It is not that commands are in common (well yes, maybe some), it is that they have the same name and do almost the same things, as for `cd` as you said.

The shells are an abstraction of the underlying operative system, Linux and Windows have a different kernel, hence the difference.

You might want to [start here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Windows_and_Linux#User_interface) with your reading.